# Remove Highcharts chart Y axis labels when legend clicked

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I am working off the Highcharts example (or any other example using multiple Yaxis) and adding multiple y-axis. The problem is when I click on the Legend to disable/remove the data from the chart, the title still appears although the axis info is removed. Anyone know how this can be disabled ?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3h5014v/)

```
  var options = {
    chart: {
    type: 'line'
  },
  yAxis: [{},{}],
  series: [{
    yAxis: 0,
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }, {
    yAxis: 0,
    data: [4, 3, 2, 1]
  }, {
    yAxis: 0,
    data: [6, 6, 6, 6]
  }, {
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [245, 523, 674, 734]
  }, {
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [200, 300, 400, 500]
  }]
}

var chart = Highcharts.chart('container',options);
```

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the `showEmpty` property:

```
    yAxis: [{
        showEmpty: false
    }, {
        showEmpty: false
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2zk78mnu/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.showEmpty